# Nested property in ResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization

I wanted help if its possible to auto resolve by Spring the nested property. I am using Spring 4.2.4, Java 8 and the property file looks like-

```
# messages.properties
company.name=XYZ
welcome.message=Dear Customers of ${company.name}
about.company=${company.name} is blah blah
```

We have a custom localization implementation to get the String from Resource bundle for i18 as defined below-

```
public String get(Locale locale, String key, Object... arguments) {
String pattern = this.getString(locale, key);
MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat(pattern, locale);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
formatter.format(arguments, buffer, null);
return buffer.toString();
}
```

I want to be able to use this method like get(locale, "welcome.message") and expect to render it as Dear Customers of XYZ.

Currently its not working failing in MessageFormat. Is there a way to allow spring auto resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use curly braces (without symbol $).
It work for Spring 5 (tested for 5.3.6 and 5.3.7):

```
# messages.properties
company.name=XYZ
welcome.message=Dear Customers of {company.name}
about.company={company.name} is blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this with *MessageSource* in my Controller like this

```
@Inject
private MessageSource message;

protected String getMessage(String key, Object[] arguments) {
    return message.getMessage(key, arguments, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. so for the above property file setup how would you resolve "Dear Customers of XYZ." message.

Comment: do you invoke String name =getMessage("company.name", null); and then String message = getMessage("welcome.message", name)

Comment: I use like Dear Customers of **{0}** or try to send the company as an argument

Comment: index works but i am looking for ideas if there is a way to auto solve this by name based nesting than index based.